# Including custom files in Publishing ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net

I have some custom files in the root of the Web application, set to "Content" and "Copy Always". when I publish the app, I can see a duplication in those files:

- A set is copied to root of the app
- Same set copied to "bin" folder

Is there a way to just copy those files to root of the app without having them copied to bin folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want them to be copied, so ensure that they are set to **Content** and not to copy.  Setting them to **Content** is all you need to ensure that they are published in the folder that they reside in.